# Getting stuck to understand the output in c

Tags: c

**How this code showing the result as 1.250000**

**I think it should show the value 0.05 but not, why?**

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int d =4;
    float f=(1/(float)d*5);
    printf("%f",f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it `1 / (d * 5)` or is it `(1 / d) * 5`? What would it be if you did it all using pen and paper? Hint: It's the same as on the computer!

Comment: What is the presidency for this expression? It is working  for / then * in this expression. I got it. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is doing 1/4 * 5 which is 1.25. Add `()` around `(float)d*5`

```
float f=(1/((float)d*5));
```

Comment: ..........Me :) @Tony

Answer (score 2):

Division and multiplication have same priority. What your code does is 1/4= 0.25, and then 0.25*5=1.25.
If you want to get 0.05 as answer change  `float f=(1/(float)d*5);` to  `float f=(1/((float)d*5));`

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication and Devision both have the same precedence and are **always executed left to right**.
So in your case, below expression will be executed as

```
float f=(1/(float)4*5);
        (1/(float)4*5) => (1/(float)4)*5 => 1.250000
                              0.250000*5 => 1.250000
```